# Jax-ws spring jpa and hibernate in mysql PersistenceContext EntityManager injection NullPointerException

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, jax-ws

i'm using jax-ws with spring jpa and hibenate in mysql. Here i was facing some issue in autowired and entitymanager return null point exception. before i was used restful application working fine. After i convert restful webservice to jax-ws using soap web service. now i changed xml configuration and added depending jar file not working in autowired and jpa entitymanager. any one please guide me.

RestFulService.java

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import com.rs.transaction.TransactionBo;
import com.rs.transaction.impl.TransactionBoImpl;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
public class RestFulService {

    @Autowired
    TransactionBo transactionBo;        

    @WebMethod(operationName="getHelloWorld")
    public String getHelloWorld(String name) {
        return "Hello World JAX-WS " + name;
    }

    @WebMethod(operationName="getAllTransaction")
    public String getAllTransaction() {
        TransactionBo transactionBo = new TransactionBoImpl();
        List<Employee> result = transactionBo.getAllTransaction();
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (Employee emp : result) {
            buffer.append(emp.getId()).append(":").append(emp.getFistName())
                    .append("\n");
        }
        System.out.println(""+buffer.toString());

        return "success";
    }
}
```

TransactionBo.java

```
public interface TransactionBo {    

    public List<Employee> getAllTransaction();


}

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.rs.transaction.TransactionBo;

@Service
public class TransactionBoImpl implements TransactionBo{

    private EntityManager entityManager;


    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }
    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Transactional
    @XmlElement(required=true, nillable=true)
    public List<Employee> getAllTransaction(){
        Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Employee.findAll");
        List<Employee> employee;
        employee = query.getResultList();
        return employee;

    }

}
```

Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
   <class>com.rs.entity.Employee</class>    

   <!--     <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
    </properties> -->
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Classpath scanning of @Component, @Service, etc annotated class -->
     <context:component-scan base-package="com.rs.entity,com.rs.rest,com.rs.transaction,com.rs.transaction.impl"/>
       <context:annotation-config />
       <tx:annotation-driven />

    <!-- MySQL Datasource with Commons DBCP connection pooling -->
    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaAdapter">
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <bean id="jpaAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
        p:database="MYSQL" p:showSql="true" />


</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>
 <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
     <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

sun-jaxws.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime"
  version="2.0">
  <endpoint
      name="HelloWorldWs"
      implementation="com.rs.rest.RestFulService"
      url-pattern="/hello"/>
</endpoints>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.jax-ws.spring</groupId>
  <artifactId>JaxRsSpring</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>JaxRsSpring</name>
  <description>Jersey Restful web service application</description>
   <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Jersey -->
         <!-- JAX-WS --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey + Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.staxex</groupId>
                    <artifactId>stax-ex</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
         <!-- Hibernate -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.Final</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.34</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency> 
    </dependencies>
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I'm resolved the problem.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
   <class>com.rs.entity.Employee</class>  
    <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
      <property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="true"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
    </properties>  
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>



@Service
public class TransactionBoImpl implements TransactionBo {

     EntityManager entityManager;


    public TransactionBoImpl(){
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnit");
        entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Employee> getAllTransaction(){
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>> "+entityManager);
        Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Employee.findAll");
        List<Employee> result = null;
        result = query.getResultList();
        return result;

    }

}

added this maven dependency
pom.xml 

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```